# How to carry out a backspace in a textarea using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an online text editor with multiple line indent and unindent functions.
The indent part works almost as expected, except for the selectionEnd flows forward when the whole text is selected and indented.
The main problem comes from the unindent part. If I select the first line after \t, then this line  won't unindent because it doesn't have any \t to replace. It's quite unrealistic to ask the users to select lines from the tabs before the text. So I was thinking if I can add a \b to the start of each line so that every line will backspace one \t when returned. But, instead of backspace one \t, it prints a box.
Thanks for any clue.

```js
$(document).delegate('#t_cont', 'keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    let start = this.selectionStart;
    let end = this.selectionEnd;
    let lines = [];
  
    if(e.shiftKey && keyCode===9){ //Shift + Tab
        e.preventDefault();
        if(start!==end){
            $(this).val().substring(start,end).split("\n").forEach(function(line){
                lines.push(line);
            });
            lines.forEach(function(line,ind){
                let tablen = line.match(/^(\t)*/)[0].length;
                let tabs = '';
                for(let i=0;i<tablen-1;i++){
                    tabs += "\t";
                }
                //lines[ind] = line.replace(/^(\t)*/,tabs);
            lines[ind] = "\b" + line;
            });
            let txt = lines.join("\n");
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0,start) + txt + $(this).val().substring(end));
            this.selectionStart = start - 1;
            this.selectionEnd = end - 2;
        }
    }else if(keyCode==9){ //Tab
        e.preventDefault();
        if(start===end){
            $(this).val(
                $(this).val().substring(0,start) + "\t" + $(this).val().substring(end)
            );
            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
        }else{
            $(this).val().substring(start,end).split("\n").forEach(function(line){
                lines.push(line);
            });
            lines.forEach(function(line,ind){
                lines[ind] = "\t" + line;
            });
            let txt = lines.join("\n");
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0,start) + txt + $(this).val().substring(end));
            this.selectionStart = start + 1;
            this.selectionEnd = end + 3;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
textarea{
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Online editor</title>
    </head>
    <body class="opt">
        <textarea id="t_cont" name="t_cont" accesskey="x">
Press Tab key to indent selected part
Shift + Tab to unindent

Mary has a little lamb.
  Mary has a little lamb.
    Mary has a little lamb.
      Mary has a little lamb.
        Mary has a little lamb.</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you back trace from selection start, to include all immediate \t chars before you split selection into lines, so that you can remove such \t on shift+tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the following code block

```
if(e.shiftKey && keyCode===9){ //Shift + Tab
 ...
}
```

to extend the selection with leading \t right before the selection, then replace leading \t on each line

```
if (e.shiftKey && keyCode === 9) { //Shift + Tab
    e.preventDefault();
    if (start !== end) {

        let backIndex = start - 1;
        while (backIndex >=0 && $(this).val().charAt(backIndex) === '\t') { backIndex--; }
        start = backIndex + 1;
        const txt = $(this).val().substring(start, end).split('\n').map(line => line.replace(/^\t/, '')).join('\n');
        
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start) + txt + $(this).val().substring(end));
        this.selectionStart = start;
        this.selectionEnd = start + txt.length;
    }
}
```